# How to Create the Summary using the Data (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, google-sheets-formula, pivot-table, flatten

I have some Data where, there are 8 columns. I want to keep Column, B,E,F,G,H and I.

In Column B I have Some positions and in other columns E,F,G,H and I  i have dates. I want to convert the dates as 1 to count the Roles, to know that how many times the date is repeated in "Headers" for the "Roles".

I have created Manually the Result Data. I have large set of data and it takes my multiple days to achieve this result.

I would really appreciate the help if it can be achieved using formula.

**DATA**

[image]

**RESULT**

[image]

[Google Sheets Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mfserC7a_YhoygdV9ZUCyTy_q4ws9jDViLNDc5Ogtf8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are you open to a script solution? It would be easy to customize if you are planning to modify it in the future.

Comment: Yes I would Appreciate if its possible

Comment: Please look into this if possible @player0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX({QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(ISDATE_STRICT(E4:I19), 
 E4:I19&"×"&B4:B19&"×"&SEQUENCE(1, 5), ), "0×a×"&SEQUENCE(5)), "×"), 
 "select Col1,Col2,count(Col2) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col1,Col2 
  pivot Col3"), 
 "offset 2", 0); "Grand Total", "", 
 TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(N(ISDATE_STRICT(E4:I19))), ROW(B4:B19)^0))})
```

or:

```
=INDEX({SORT({QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(ISDATE_STRICT(E4:I19), 
 E4:I19&"×"&B4:B19&"×"&SEQUENCE(1, 5), ), "0×a×"&SEQUENCE(5)), "×"), 
 "select Col1,Col2,count(Col2) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col1,Col2 
  pivot Col3"), 
 "offset 2", 0); QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(ISDATE_STRICT(E4:I19), 
 E4:I19&"×"&SEQUENCE(1, 5), ), "0×"&SEQUENCE(5)), "×"), 
 "select Col1,'Total',count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  pivot Col2"), 
 "offset 2", 0)}); "Grand Total", "", 
 TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(N(ISDATE_STRICT(E4:I19))), ROW(B4:B19)^0))})
```

---

or as you requested:

```
={"Date Sourced", B3, E3:I3;
 INDEX({SORT({QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(ISDATE_STRICT(E4:I), 
 E4:I&"×"&B4:B&"×"&SEQUENCE(1, 5), ), "0×a×"&SEQUENCE(5)), "×"), 
 "select Col1,Col2,count(Col2) 
  where Col2 is not null group by Col1,Col2 pivot Col3"), 
 "offset 2", 0); QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(ISDATE_STRICT(E4:I), 
 E4:I&"×"&SEQUENCE(1, 5), ), "0×"&SEQUENCE(5)), "×"), 
 "select Col1,'Total',count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"), 
 "offset 2", 0)}); "Grand Total", "", 
 TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(N(ISDATE_STRICT(E4:I))), ROW(B4:B)^0))})}
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gg_jFl0Lk3hEl-g5CiP_Xm_YIy3eGJr3WI25ze4xxK0/copy)

Comment: Thank you very much! You are Genius its unbelievable. One more favor please Is it possible to add Header Name in the formula.

Comment: @HSHO answer updated. see demo sheet

Answer (score 1):

If you are still open with an apps script solution:

#### Script:

```
function createSummary() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var timezone = spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var locale = spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetLocale().replace('_', '-');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  // Assuming data starts at B3
  var startRow = 4;
  var startCol = 2;
  // Get all data (B4:I)
  var data = sheet.getRange(startRow, startCol, lastRow - startRow + 1, 8).getDisplayValues();
  // Get unique dates to iterate later
  var dates = uniqueDate(data.map(r => [r[3], r[4], r[5], r[6], r[7]]), timezone);
  // Instantiate headers
  var headers = ['Date Sourced', 'Role', 'Interested Date', 'Link', 'Screened', 'Interviewed', 'Offer'];
  // Add headers as first row in the output later
  var output = [headers];
  // Variable to store daily Totals for Grand Total
  var grandTotal = new Array(5).fill(0);

  // Iterate dates
  dates.forEach(date => {
    // Dictionary to store data
    var dateRoles = {};
    // Iterate data
    data.forEach(row => {
      // Iterate headers with date values
      headers.slice(2).forEach((header, index) => {
        // If date iterated is equal to header value for that date
        if(new Date(row[index + 3]).toDateString() == new Date(date).toDateString()) {
          // Save data in dictionary
          var role = row[0];
          var key = `${date}_${role}_${header}`;
          // If key is existing, iterate value
          if (key in dateRoles)
            dateRoles[key]++;
          // Else, initialize to 1
          else
            dateRoles[key] = 1;
        }
      });
    });
    var subOutput = [];
    // Roles present in current date with date values (sorted)
    var roles = [...new Set(Object.keys(dateRoles).map(role => role.split('_')[1]))].sort();
    // Iterate unique available roles for the date
    roles.forEach((role, i) => {
      // If first row, use date as first column, else blank
      var first = '';
      if(!i)
        first = date;

      subOutput.push([first, role, dateRoles[`${date}_${role}_${headers[2]}`], dateRoles[`${date}_${role}_${headers[3]}`],
                                dateRoles[`${date}_${role}_${headers[4]}`], dateRoles[`${date}_${role}_${headers[5]}`],
                                dateRoles[`${date}_${role}_${headers[6]}`]]);
    });
    // Sub Totals
    var subTotals = [subTotal(subOutput, 2), subTotal(subOutput, 3), subTotal(subOutput, 4), 
                     subTotal(subOutput, 5), subTotal(subOutput, 6)];
    // Add Total per date
    subOutput.push(['', 'Total'].concat(subTotals));
    // Add sub Totals to Grand Total
    grandTotal = grandTotal.map(function (num, idx) {
      return num + parseInt(subTotals[idx] || 0);
    }); 
    // Add daily output to final output
    output = output.concat(subOutput);
  });
  // Append Grand Total
  output.push(['Grand Total', ''].concat(grandTotal));
  // Write data starting at L3
  sheet.getRange(3, 12, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output)
}

// Function to get sub totals
function subTotal(data, index) {
  var total = data.map(r => r[index]).reduce((a, b) => (a || 0) + (b || 0), 0);
  if (total < 1) 
    return '';
  return total;
}

// Get Unique Date
function uniqueDate(data, timezone) {
  var dates = data.flat()
                  .map(date => new Date(date))
                  .filter(date => (date instanceof Date));
  return dates.map(date => date.getTime())
              .sort()
              .filter((date, i, array) => array.indexOf(date) === i)
              .map(time => Utilities.formatDate(new Date(time), timezone, "dd-MMM-yyyy"));
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you very much. It would be great to learn this script and glad you have mentioned the comments.